# X x() not creating object C++

Tags: c++, oop

I've encountered the next code:

```
class X{
};
int main() {
    X x1;
    X x2();
    X x3 = X();
}
```

why does `X x2();` is not creating an object?

Comment: Why do you indicate that the object is not created?

Comment: Because it is a function (declaration), not an object.

Comment: @Ron How do you assume it's a function?

Comment: Most vexing parse doesn't play a role here. But yeah, it's a fuction declaration.

Comment: @eyllanesc - Because that's what it is.

Comment: If your compiler is up-to-this-decade, you should be able to use the uniform initialization syntax introduced in C++11: `X x2{};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 X x2();
```

Is a prototype.

It declares that a function `x2` will exist, that takes no parameters, and has a return value of type `X`.

It should be followed up with a usage of `x2`:

```
myX = x2(); // calling function x2 for a result
```

and also an implementation of `x2`:

```
X x2() { return go_get_value(); }
```